# Erro de URL em pesquisa no google com Laravel

Tags: laravel

Fala pessoal, estou com o seguinte problema desenvolvi este site [aqui](http://www.passebemconcursos.com.br/), se vocês irem no google e digitar passe bem concursos ele aparece no buscador tranquilamente, porem isso na versão desktop. Agora se tentar acessar na versão mobile no google ele acha o site mais ao invés de usar a `URL` padrão que seria `www.passebemconcursos.com.br` ele faz isso `m.passebemconcursos.com.br` e isso faz com que a página não abra mais se eu ir e digitar na barra de pesquisa no navegador a `URL` correta ela abre tranquilamente o problema mesmo está sendo quando fazem a busca do site no próprio google.
Estou usando `laravel` gostaria de saber se tem como converter essa `URL` para a correta.

Comment: Veja isso aqui: https://laravel-news.com/2014/06/laravel-user-agent-and-mobile-detection/

Comment: @seamusd obrigado amigo mais essas tags elas vão aonde no meu código nos routes nos controllers ? sou meio novato ainda

Comment: Kirito eu não sei nada de Laravel também, mas sugiro que você dê um ctrl+F, faça uma busca no projeto inteiro verificando se existe o `isMobile()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal conseguir resolver meu problema aqui está a resposta caso alguém tenha o mesmo erro eu abri o arquivo **.HTACESS** e coloquei um `redirect`

```
redirect 301 http://m.seusite.com.br/aquivo_novo.htm http://www.seusite.com.br/aquivo_novo.htm
```